# require.js - undefined modules passed as arguments to define callback

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

I have the following require js setup for my app:

**app.js**

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: '../thirdparty/jquery-1.9.1.min',
        moment: '../thirdparty/moment',
        spinningwheel: '../thirdparty/datepicker/spinningwheel',
        handlebars: '../thirdparty/handlebars',
        colorgenerator: '../usercolors',
        baseconfig: '../config'        },
    shim: {
        'baseconfig': [],
        'spinningwheel': {
            deps: [],
            exports: 'SpinningWheel'
        },
        'handlebars': {
            deps: [],
            exports: 'Handlebars'
        }

    }
});


require(['jquery', 'dom', 'helpers', 'actions', 'history', 'store'], function ($, dom, helpers, actions, hist, store) {
    //all good on the home front at this point
    //all modules loaded properly
    history.render();
})
```

**history.js**

```
define(['renderview'], function (renderview) {
    //all good here, render view is loaded properly
    return {
        render: function () {
            renderview({...});
        }
    };
})
```

**renderview.js**

```
define(['jquery', 'helpers', 'dom'], function ($, helpers, dom) {
    function renderView(view) {
        var template = helpers.getTemplate(); //ERROR: helpers is undefined!
    }

    return renderView;
});
```

**helpers.js**

```
define(['jquery', 'handlebars', 'history', 'dom', 'colorgenerator'], function ($, Handlebars, history, dom, ColorGenerator) {
    var helpers = {};

    helpers.getTemplate = function () {
       //do stuff
    };

    return helpers;
});
```

So, as you can see, helpers is loaded just fine in the inital app.js callback, but when I get into renderview.js it is undefined.  The dependency arrays in the example are exactly what I have in my actual code, however I've redacted all *seemingly* irrelevant code.  Any ideas why helpers would be loaded fine in app.js but not in renderview.js?  Is this a circular dependency?  Doesn't look like it to me, but I may have been at this too long today :)

Thanks for any help or suggestions!

**Adding current solution, although I don't know why I need to do it this way :)**

```
define(['require', 'jquery', 'dom'], function (require, $, dom) {
    function renderView() {
        //responsible for rendering our view
        var helpers = require('helpers');
        var history = require('history');

        var v = history.get();
        ...
        tmpl = helpers.getTemplate(v.template);
        ...
    }

    return renderView;
});
```

So, I could not get these modules to load properly without doing the require *inside* the callback, rather than specifying them as a dependency.  Would love some insight to why that is...

Comment: In the not watered down code does helpers have a getTemplate method?

Comment: yes sir.  I'll edit for clarity.  In the renderview.js, the **helpers** argument is undefined though, not just that function.

Comment: Got this working, but not sure why I had to implement this fix.  I ended up having to require the "require" module, and then doing "require('helpers')" from within the renderview function.  Not sure why, but that seems to make things work.

Comment: Yeh, the only thing I thought about was perhaps it was getting buried in functions calls and not accessible, but I've never had that problem with requirejs before so I figured it wasn't that. One day down the road when you refactor you'll probably stumble about the solution you really wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Given the problem and your solution, it looks like you have a [circular dependency](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#circular) somewhere in your require calls. Maybe some of the modules that you require in the `helper` module also require the `helpers` module.

Comment: If that was true, shouldn't it be logged?